# Is there a way to verify user permissions with win32security

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I know about win32security.LogonUser. What I want to do is check credentials that were entered to know whether or not they match a user on the local windows machine, and password, so that I can grant them access to the windows machine via the network. The idea is to have a pythonic ssh server made with paramiko that has default windows authentication. What I don't want to have to do is log the user out each time a new connection is established or have the authentication process fail because the user is already logged in. Is there a way to verify a user on windows without creating a login session?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what `LogonUser` does. It creates a _new_ logon token for the user, independent of any others the user may have. It will not fail just because the user is already logged in locally, nor will it affect that local session. Read [the documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info—or just try it out.

Comment: Also… presumably the access you want to grant them is access _as themselves_, not as whatever user account is running the server, right? In that case, you need a logon token to pass to `CreateProcessAsUser`, so you don't really have a choice here. (Well, you could run the service with privs that allow it to impersonate all users, but that's a pretty silly thing to do if you're forcing them to send their username and password.)

Comment: abarnert is really asking why you didnt just try logonuser since it works basically just like you ask for it to in your question :P